# Cannot iterate dplyr::bind_cols from an empty tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I want to create the following tibble by starting with an empty `tibble`

```
expected = tibble::tibble(z = 1:10, w = 2:11)
```

However, the following code doesn't work and shows the error.

```
actual= tibble::tibble()
actual = dplyr::bind_cols(actual, tibble::tibble(z = 1:10))
actual = dplyr::bind_cols(actual, tibble::tibble(w = 2:11))

Error: Can't recycle `..1` (size 0) to match `..2` (size 10).
```

The version of dplyr is 1.0.0 and that of tibble is 3.0.1.
This code has no problem in dplyr old version 0.8.3

---

Thanks for your comments. Sorry for my insufficient explanation.
To be accurate, I want to use only dplyr::bind_cols in iteration.

```
actual= tibble::tibble()
tibbles = list(tibble::tibble(z = 1:10),
               tibble::tibble(w = 2:11))     
for(i in 1:length(tibbles)){
   actual = dplyr::bind_cols(actual, tibbles[[i]])
}
```

Comment: I get `Error: Argument 2 must be length 0, not 10` in `dplyr` 0.8.3 and the same error message as you on `dplyr` 1.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

You want `bind_rows()` not `bind_cols()` in your first update:

```
actual= tibble::tibble()
actual = dplyr::bind_rows(actual, tibble::tibble(z = 1:10))
actual = dplyr::bind_cols(actual, tibble::tibble(w = 2:11))
actual
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       z     w
   <int> <int>
 1     1     2
 2     2     3
 3     3     4
 4     4     5
 5     5     6
 6     6     7
 7     7     8
 8     8     9
 9     9    10
10    10    11
```